# nested json api respone to python dataframe

Tags: python, json

i am using api response to get indian pin codes list along with state , country and many names, which are in postofflice field, i want dedicated dataframe for that postoffice field, please help

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

response = requests.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/110094")
data = json.loads(response.text)

json_normalize(data)

res = [ sub['PostOffice'] for sub in data ]
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? What is your problem ? As it is, your question is too broad for us to help you. As a new member of Stack Overflow, don't hesitate to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/110094")
data = json.loads(response.text)

postOffices = pd.DataFrame(data[0]['PostOffice'])
```

After that you can access every element like this:

```py
print(postOffices.loc[0])
```

Output:

```py
Name                        Dayalpur
Description                     None
BranchType        Branch Post Office
DeliveryStatus          Non-Delivery
Circle                         Delhi
District            North East Delhi
Division                  Delhi East
Region                         Delhi
Block                             NA
State                          Delhi
Country                        India
Pincode                       110094
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: i want to add details of furthur elements along side in below output and make a dataframe,please help.

Comment: What do you mean?